# How to pull page analysis data from SharePoint and display it on Power BI?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, devops, power-automate

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve page analysis data from SharePoint and display it on Power BI. Specifically, I'm interested in metrics such as page views, unique visitors, and other custom analytics data.

I've explored the built-in analytics features in SharePoint but couldn't find a direct option to export or integrate the data with Power BI. prefer it to be live updates but anything to get me started works.

Could someone please guide me on the steps involved in pulling the page analysis data from SharePoint and integrating it into Power BI? I would appreciate any insight.

Thank you

What I have tried:

1. Exporting data through admin.microsoft: I attempted to export the data from SharePoint using the admin.microsoft portal.

2.Pulling data through the URL: I also attempted to retrieve the page analysis data by constructing the appropriate URL. However, I encountered an error message.

Answer (score 0):

As a start I would suggest to have a look at the two Graph API endpoints below.

SharePoint activity reports
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0

SharePoint site usage reports
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint-site-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0